# Tortoise and the Hare Race with Arrays and Pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, error-handling

My assignment requires me to recreate the tortoise and the hare race in c programming using pointers. This is what I have come up with so far. My code basically prints 70 rows of arrays all assigned to 0 and if a position in an array is 2 or 3 that is where the tortoise or the hare is and if there is a one it means they clashed based on their movements which are decided randomly. I have several problems with my code.

1. It runs as I expected but at the end it prints out an error saying segmentation fault(core dumped).
2. It is not printing the winner as I told it to.
3. Only my Hare seems to be moving randomly. Ther are no patterns in its movement whereas my Tortoise doesn't seem to be moving randomly. It is following a diagonal line.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define CLASH 1
#define TORT 2
#define HARE 3

void moveHare(int *hPtr);
void moveTortoise(int *tPtr);
void printCurrentPositions(int *hPtr, int *tPtr);
int main (void)
{
    // variables 
    static int hare = 0;
    static int tortoise = 0;
    static int *hPtr = &hare;
    static int *tPtr = &tortoise;
    int timer = 0;
    
     srand ( time(NULL) );
     puts("ON YOUR MARK, GET SET\nBANG !!!!!\nAND THEY'RE OFF!!!!!\n");
     puts("HT");
    
    //while the race is not finished
    while (tortoise <= 70 || hare <= 70)
    {
        moveHare(&hare);
        moveTortoise(&tortoise);
        printCurrentPositions(&hare, &tortoise);
        timer++;
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    //if functions if one of them wins
    if (hare > tortoise)
    {
        puts("\nHARE WINS!!!");
        printf("It took %d seconds", timer);
            
            
    }
    else if (tortoise > hare)
    {
        puts("\nTORTOISE WINS");
        printf("It took %d seconds", timer);
    }
    
}


//functions for the Hare's movement
void moveHare(int *hPtr)
{
    int randomValue = rand () % 10 + 1;
    
    if (randomValue == 1 || randomValue == 2)
     {
        *hPtr += 0;
     }
     else if (randomValue == 3 || randomValue == 4)
     {
        *hPtr += 9;
     }
     else if (randomValue == 5)
     {
        *hPtr -= 12;
     }
     else if (randomValue>=6 && randomValue <=8)
     {
        *hPtr += 1;
     }
     else if(randomValue>=9)
     {
        *hPtr -= 2;
     }
}

// function for the Tortoise's movement
void moveTortoise( int *tPtr ){
    
     int randomValue  = rand() % 10 + 1;
     
     if (randomValue >= 1 && randomValue <=5)
     {
        *tPtr += 3;
     }
     else if(randomValue == 6 || randomValue == 7)
     {
         *tPtr -= 6;
     }
     else if(randomValue >= 8)
     {
        *tPtr += 1;
     }

    
}

//printing their current positions based on the 
void printCurrentPositions(int *hPtr, int *tPtr)
{
    int Array[70] = {0};
    
    if (*hPtr == *tPtr)
    {
        Array[*hPtr] = CLASH;
    }
    else  
    {
        
        Array[*hPtr] = HARE;
        Array[*tPtr] = TORT;
    }
    
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 70; i++)
    {
        if (Array[i] == 0)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        else if (Array[i] == TORT)
        {
            printf("T");
        }
        else if (Array[i] == HARE)
        {
            printf("H");
        }
        else if (Array[i] == CLASH)
        {
            printf("OUCH!");
        }
        
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Ok so I have fixed the two mistakes pointed out; one about my off-by-one error and the other one which is about my conditions for checking if the value is between two numbers. But I still keep on seeing this core dumped error and I can't get to print who the winner is. @MikeCat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `printCurrentPositions` contains off-by-one error. `Array` has only 70 elements (`Array[0]` to `Array[69]`), so you must not read `Array[70]`. The condition of the `for` statement should be `i < 70`, not `i <= 70`.

Also the function is not checking the value of `*hPtr` and `*tPtr`. You have to make sure that they are non-negative and less than 70 to avoid out-of-range write.

Finally, some of conditions used in `movehare` and `moveTortoise` are wrong. The conditions `randomValue>=6 || randomValue <=8` and `randomValue >= 1 || randomValue <=5` will always be true. They should be `randomValue>=6 && randomValue <=8` and `randomValue >= 1 && randomValue <=5`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you meant by the function is not checking the value of *hPtr and *tPtr? Which function are you specifically talking about @MikeCAT? Also, I fixed the errors about the value checking and the off by one error in my for loop but I still see the core dumped error, and  I still cant print who the winner is.

Comment: @Beakal The function `printCurrentPositions` is using `Array[*hPtr]` and `Array[*tPtr]` without checking the value of `*hPtr` and `*tPtr`.

Comment: That function is taking in a pointer that contains a number. All I am trying to do is to go to a specific array space according to that number. I didn't think a checking will be needed.@MikeCAT

Comment: @Beakal Then your thought is wrong. The values may be made out-of-range by the functions `moveHare` and `moveTortoise`, and range check is required to prevent out-of-range write to the array `Array`.